# Validacion de Letras en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, regex, grocery-crud

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) con el apoyo de `Grocery CRUD`, pero al momento de hacer una validación no la reconoce, lo que necesito es que un campo sea validado para aceptar sólo caracteres alfabéticos, además de puntos, coma y espacios pero no funciona:

```
public function solo_letras($cadena)
{
    $patron = '/[a-zA-Z,.\s]*$/';
    if( !preg_match( $patron, $cadena ) ) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Lineas de código en la función del Grocery CRUD en la cuál llamo a la función `solo_letras`

```
if( $this->input->post( 'marca' ) != null ) {
    $crud->set_rules( 'marca', 'Marca', 'alpha|callback_solo_letras' );
}
```

¿Cual seria una validación que podría ocupar?

Comment: Que problema tienes con ese código?, te sigue aceptando otros caracteres? te lanza algún error?

Comment: Si me sigue mandando el mensaje predefinido aunque le introduzca datos como "Stack Overflow" o "Stack, Overflow"

Comment: Que mensaje predefinido? Intenta probando con la siguiente expresión regular: `'/^[a-zA-Z,.\s]*$/'`

Comment: Intente con la expresion regular que me proporcionaste pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al estar usando `alpha` como primera regla, estás limitando el ingreso a que sean sólo letras. Con esa regla estás prohibiendo que ingresen espacios, comas o puntos. Hay que eliminar esa regla:

```php
$crud->set_rules( 'marca', 'Marca', 'callback_solo_letras' );
```

Por otro lado, la expresión regular debería

1. estar [anclada al inicio del texto](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.anchors.php) con `^`.
2. sólo permitir espacios (ya que `\s` permite [cualquier espacio en blanco](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php) o `[ \t\r\n\f]`)

```regex
/^[a-z ,.]*$/i
```

Y la función quedaría:

```php
public function solo_letras($cadena)
{
    return preg_match( '/^[a-z ,.]*$/i', $cadena );
}
```

---

Sin embargo, es mucho más sencillo utilizar la regla [`regex_match[/regex/]`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference)

```php
$crud->set_rules( 'marca', 'Marca', 'regex_match[/^[a-z ,.]*$/i]' );
```

- O si se quiere permitir `ñ` y otras letras del español:

  ```php
  $crud->set_rules( 'marca', 'Marca', 'regex_match[/^[a-zñáéíóúüA-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚÜ ,.]*$/u]' );
  ```
- O cualquier letra de cualquier alfabeto (categoría general [Letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) de Unicode).

  ```php
  $crud->set_rules( 'marca', 'Marca', 'regex_match[/^[\p{L} ,.]*$/u]' );
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Es Justo lo que andaba buscando..